# How to traverse code downward to find the nearest <a> tag that will be under a different parent?

Tags: javascript, html

I am making a Chrome extension that works with Facebook, and, Facebooks class naming conventions make it so that it's nearly impossible to search/traverse the DOM using classes, so you have to get creative. For this one function, it's done on a page that will have a list of users, and to target each user's "block" there is only one single consistent piece of the DOM that I can target as a starting point, which is an SVG.

Right above the SVG there is a link to the users profile, which was fairly simple for me to traverse to using closest() but for reasons that are not important for this post, I can't do this anymore, and the only other existence of this profile URL that I need to extract is below the SVG and under a different parent, and I am having trouble targeting it.

Here is my existing code that works fine 95% of the time, but I've found an edge case on Facebook's side that I can't prevent, so now I have to traverse to the `<a>` *below* the SVG instead of the one you will see above it that I'm using now.

```js
if (node.querySelector("svg")) {
   var profileEle = node.querySelector("svg").first("a");
```

*Note: This DOM has a huge amount of code and obfuscated classes that change all the time -- I removed 90% of that to make it easier to read, but I retained the structure so everything relevant is still here.*

```html
<div class="x9f619 x1n2onr6">
  <div class="x9f619 x5f2onr5 ">    
        <a aria-label="Fakename Brown" href="/user/1000062068387/" role="link">
          <div class="x1rg5ohu x1n2onr6">
            <svg aria-hidden="true" class="x3ajldb">
              <mask id=":r71:"></mask>
            </svg>
          </div>
        </a>    
  </div>
  <div class="x9f619 x1n2onr6 ">    
        <span class="x193iq5w xeuugli">
          <span class="x1dawdq5w">
            <span class="xt0psk2">
              <a href="/user/1000062068387/" role="link" >Fakename Brown</a>
            </span>
          </span>
        </span>      
  </div>
</div>
```

In the above code, I was originally targeting the `<a>` tag above the SVG, but I now realized that because of the edge case I mentioned, I have to target the `<a>` below the SVG, and you have to go 4 or 5 parents up before you get to the one that they share, and I am struggling figuring out how to traverse downward (or maybe upward to the shared parent and *then* downward?) to reach the `<a>` that is below.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

To target an `<a>` element that is inside a `<div>` that itself is a sibling of another `<div>` which does contain an `<a>` which does contain an `<svg>`, the CSS selector is `div:has(a svg) ~ div a` (if you target older browsers, see [this compatibility table](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:has#browser_compatibility)).

```js
console.log(document.querySelector("div:has(a svg) ~ div a").textContent);
```

```html
<div class="x9f619 x1n2onr6">
  <div class="x9f619 x5f2onr5 ">
    <a aria-label="Fakename Brown" href="/user/1000062068387/" role="link">
      <div class="x1rg5ohu x1n2onr6">
        <svg aria-hidden="true" class="x3ajldb">
          <mask id=":r71:"></mask>
        </svg>
      </div>
    </a>
  </div>
  <div class="x9f619 x1n2onr6 ">
    <span class="x193iq5w xeuugli">
      <span class="x1dawdq5w">
        <span class="xt0psk2">
          <a href="/user/1000062068387/" role="link" >Fakename Brown</a>
        </span>
    </span>
    </span>
  </div>
</div>
```

But while this selector will work with the minimal example you gave, it's relatively broad and it can possibly match other elements before this one. If you can make it more specific by any means, make it so.